# Save webview content to android storage and load it

Tags: android, html, webview, storage

I want to make an android application which has a webview layout. This is the criteria of my application:

1. The first time the application starts, webview loads an url (maybe facebook, google, etc..)
   webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
2. After it loads the url, the application saves the loaded url to HTML View (file.htm) in a "specific place" in android's internal storage. So, let's say i open "google.com", the application saves the google's web page to HTML file (let's say the filename, "google.htm"), and when i go to that "specific place" and click the "google.htm" file, it shows the google web page using android's HTML Viewer.
3. When the application starts again, or simply say the application loads the url again (in this case, "google.com") , it doesn't take from the "google.com" page BUT it takes from the "google.htm" file on the internal storage android. So from the user's view, that application can still load webpages, even though it's not connected to internet.

To make it simple,

1. Application Start -> Go to the specified url -> Check the storage
2. IF there's the specified url HAS the HTML file in the storage, then load from the storage
3. ELSE it loads the url from the web.

Can anyone help me with the code and explanation? I really appreciate it. Thanks guys :D

Comment: did you try something already? did you encounter any problem while doing so? do you need architecture advice? because this site isn't a code dispenser.

Comment: could you please provide the full source code i cant manage the above code to work..
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Javascript interface for the WebView to return the entirety of the HTML source when the page is finished loading. To do this, you'll need to assign your own WebViewClient to the WebView.

To do this, use something similar to the following in your Activity class -- **Make sure your Activity implements Observer**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    HtmlJSInterface htmlJSInterface = new HtmlJSInterface();
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(htmlJSInterface, "HTMLOUT");
    htmlJSInterface.addObserver(this);

    // ...
}

// Called when our JavaScript Interface Observables are updated.
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object observation) {

    // Got full page source.
    if (observable instanceof HtmlJSInterface) {
        html = (String) observation;
        onHtmlChanged();
    }
}

private void onHtmlChanged() {
    // Do stuff here...
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // When each page is finished we're going to inject our custom
        // JavaScript which allows us to
        // communicate to the JS Interfaces. Responsible for sending full
        // HTML over to the
        // HtmlJSInterface...
        isStarted = false;
        isLoaded = true;
        timeoutTimer.cancel();
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                + "window.HTMLOUT.setHtml('<html>'+"
                + "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');})();");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you're going to want to create the HtmlJSInterface class, as such:

```
   public class HtmlJSInterface extends Observable {
  private String html;

  /**
   * @return The most recent HTML received by the interface
   */
  public String getHtml() {
    return this.html;
  }

  /**
   * Sets most recent HTML and notifies observers.
   * 
   * @param html
   *          The full HTML of a page
   */
  public void setHtml(String html) {
    this.html = html;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(html);
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, please ignore the extra variables and Timer in onPageFinished(). :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, where is this html file is going to be saved in the internal storage?

Comment: Assuming this will ignore the CSS properties and scripts

Comment: @mahe madhi this will pick up only css embedded in the page itself, but you can use a parser and client to fetch the link hrefs, just be aware of the extra overhead

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `saveWebArchive`

```
private fun offlineSave(webView1:WebView, webView2:WebView) {
    webView1.loadUrl("https://example.com/privacy")

    val settings = webView1.settings
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    Handler().postDelayed({//you can do onPageFinished
        val imageFile = File(filesDir, "doc.mht")
        webView1.saveWebArchive(imageFile.path, false, ValueCallback<String?> {
            Log.e("***** saved", "saved")
            runOnUiThread {
                val settings = webView2.settings

                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
                settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true)
                settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
                settings.setAllowContentAccess(true)
                settings.setAllowFileAccess(true)
                settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
                settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true)

                webView2.loadUrl("file://" + imageFile.path)
            }
        })
    }, 4000)

    runOnUiThread {
        val imageFile = File(filesDir, "doc.mht")
        val settings = webView2.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true)
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true)
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true)
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true)
        webView2.loadUrl("file://" + imageFile.path)
    }
}
```