# WebView - Download javascript, css and images

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-webview

I am saving the content of WebView so that I can show that content when I launch my app the next time. I followed [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832462/save-webview-content-to-android-storage-and-load-it) which works almost as I wanted.

```
@JavascriptInterface
        public void setHtml(String html) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
            this.html = html;
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("ActivityHtml", html);
            prefEditor.commit();
            Log.d("html", html);
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(html);
        }
```

And then :

```
view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", settings.getString("ActivityHtml", ""), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

However, when I see the html in Log, the Javascript and CSS have server paths like :

```
<link href="/Content/Sass/style_sass.css?version=1.0.1.15" rel="stylesheet">  
<img src="../Images/magnify_black.png" />
```

Now because of this, only the text content shows up while the images aren't shown. Like this :

[image]

How may I get the images, css and javascript in HTML ?

Just to tell I already have following in place :

```
view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You're providing no base URL so the WebView doesn't know where to find the assets. Are they in your `assets` folder in your APK? If so, `view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", ...`. If these assets aren't downloaded anywhere, you'll need to use the original website's URL as the base

Comment: Try to load CSS from Assets: by using `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", yourdata, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

Comment: @RGraham : You got me :) Please post an answer.

Comment: @Nitish You should post an answer yourself to let people know where you pulled the assets from - it'll be more accurate! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load CSS from Assets or SDcard,just like this:

```
    WebView wv = new WebView(context);
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.append("<html>");
    html.append("<head>");
    html.append("<link rel=stylesheet href='css/style.css'>");
    html.append("</head>");
    html.append("<body>");
    html.append("<h1>Some Heading</h1>");
    html.append("<p>Some HTML content</p>");
    html.append("<p><img style='width: 100%;' src='spidermen.jpg' /></p>");
    html.append("</body></html>");
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

and put the files in the right place.

[image: webview]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
view.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",settings.getString("ActivityHtml", ""),"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and the CSS part you need to place it locally in your assets folder.