# Save .html file into internal storage using OkHttp lib

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm new to android and I'm trying to create app that save's `.html` page into internal storage to open it later in the `WebView`. I want to do that using `OkHttp` library but, I don't know how to do that. Maybe there is some opportunity to get code of the page in the `String` and store it into html? Help me please.

Comment: with which app do you open the html webpage? with an other webView? then -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832462/save-webview-content-to-android-storage-and-load-it

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similàr and this is how I saved mine.

```
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056097/save-html-file-into-internal-storage-using-okhttp-lib#";
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
final String url = sharedText;
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
        Log.e("APp", e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            output = response.body().string();
            //You can then save the output in your database
        }else {
            //You can return an error since the response was not successful
            Log.e("APp", "Error");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how get page encoding