# OkHTTP page source

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm trying to get `html` page source using `OkHTTP` library. But the following code does not return code of the page. Help me please to get the code of the web page.

```
private void loadUrl() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        try {
            post(client, currentUrl, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String responseStr = response.body().string();
                        // Do what you want to do with the response.
                    } else {
                        // Request not successful
                    }
                }
            }).;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    private Call post(OkHttpClient client, String url, Callback callback) throws IOException{
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(callback);
        return call;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answered the same question here [Save .html file into internal storage using OkHttp lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056097/save-html-file-into-internal-storage-using-okhttp-lib/33062744#33062744). Your code is supposed to work. But, I just found out that OkHttp returns error for URL that have # at the end like this [OkHTTP page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056658/okhttp-page-source#)