# How to store a html file locally in android securely

Tags: android, webview

How to save a html page when the webview has finished loading ? Basically I have an app which uses firebase hosting to serve webapges . As the firebase hosting is limited so I  need to save my html file as the user has successfully loaded an html page on his device(Off course securely so that these html data can't be stolen by attackers)  . In this way when the user wants to access this html page, he will load it from his device and not from the server .
I searched a lot in stackoverflow and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832462/save-webview-content-to-android-storage-and-load-it). But I can't understand it clearly . Can anyone help me to get rid of it.
Can anyone answer these problems I've mentioned below:

1. How to get the html content from the webview after it has finised loading ?
2. How to securely store this html content so that any other app can't access it ?

Comment: Save your file to getFilesDir().

Comment: I could'nt get you. Can you please explain in some detail.

Comment: @blackapps I just wanted to know how to get save the html content and where should I do that ?

Comment: You should formulate better. You have three problems, First: How the get the html source of a WebView in a string variable?. Second: How to save the hlml source in that string variable to file? Third: What would be a suitable storage location to store that file so it is secure? The third you dont have to ask anymore as i already told you in my first comment.

Comment: `How to store a html file locally in android securely` You mean: `How to store the html source of a WebView locally in my Adroid device securely?`

Comment: Humm...I get it @blackapps, I can clearly understand what you have said about the third problem . But what about the first and second problem ?

Comment: Reformulate your post. Clearly separate it in two or three problems. When you have done that i will delete all my comments and then all starts as new. Also modify the subject.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Not yet the subject. And your second one is unclear. You better split it.  Put the three as i proposed.